# How to insert visual elements inside the Java text editor of IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I'd like to add extra visual elements inside the Java text editor of IntelliJ, more specifically **on top of classes and methods declarations**. Things like indicators and links.

The best example is what Microsoft has done in Visual Studio with what they call CodeLens:

[image: Visual Studio CodeLens]

The closest solution I can think of is using [Line Markers](http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/tutorials/custom_language_support/line_marker_provider.html) (displayed in the gutter) but it's far from the user experience I want to have.

Are there any IntelliJ plugins that have done this before?

Any pointers to give me somewhere to start?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not supported by the IntelliJ IDEA editor API. You can try using a JLayeredPane to do custom painting on top of an editor, but this would be fairly difficult to implement and fragile.

Comment: Right, and it gets even more complicated as I would have to add some extra spacing above the method/class declarations...

Comment: This would be not "even more complicated" but rather impossible. You can't modify the layout of the text displayed in an IntelliJ IDEA editor.